# What are the algebras for the ultrafilter monad on topological spaces?

Tags: ct.category-theory, gn.general-topology, monads

**Motivation:** Let $(X,\tau)$ be a topological space. Then the set $\beta X$ of ultrafilters on $X$ admits a natural topology (cf. Example 5.14 in [Adámek and Sousa - D-ultrafilters and their monads](https://arxiv.org/abs/1909.04950)), giving rise to a functor $\beta: \operatorname{Top} \to \operatorname{Top}$ which admits the structure of a [monad](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/monad). It turns out that the [algebras](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/monad#Algebras) for this monad, which I'll call "$\beta$-spaces", admit the following description (which one can alternatively take as a definition).

**Definition:** A *$\beta$-space* consists of a topological space $(X,\tau)$ equipped with an additional topology $\tau^\xi$ on $X$ such that

1. $(X, \tau^\xi)$ is compact Hausdorff;
2. The topology $\tau^\xi$ refines the topology $\tau$; and
3. For every $x \in X$ and every $\tau$-open neighborhood $U$ of $x$, there exists a $\tau$-open neighborhood $V$ of $x$ such that the $\tau^\xi$-closure of $V$ is contained in $U$.

**Notes:**

- From (1) and (2) it follows that $(X,\tau)$ is compact.
- So if $(X,\tau)$ is additionally Hausdorff, then it admits a unique $\beta$-space structure, namely the one with $\tau^\xi = \tau$ (since continuous bijections of compact Hausdorff spaces are homeomorphisms).
- $(X,\tau)$ need not be Hausdorff—e.g., if $\tau$ is the indiscrete topology, then the topology $\tau^\xi$ can be an arbitrary compact Hausdorff topology.
- The compact Hausdorff topology $\tau^\xi$ traces back to [Manes' theorem](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/ultrafilter#comphaus), which says that the algebras for the ultrafilter monad on $\operatorname{Set}$ rather than $\operatorname{Top}$ are precisely the compact Hausdorff spaces.

**Questions:**

1. Are there additional restrictions on the topology $(X,\tau)$ such that it admits a refinement $\tau^\xi$ satisfying (1), (2), (3) (i.e. constituting a $\beta$-space), beyond the fact, as noted, that $X$ must be compact?
2. Do $\beta$-spaces already have some other name? Or at least, is condition (3) above, relating a topology $\tau$ to a refinement $\tau^\xi$, something which has a name?

Comment: This is so cool. I missed good point topology problems :)

Comment: @AndreaMarino I agree! I think it's worthwhile to revisit some of these classic things from time to time. Manes' theorem, in particular, is a gem which deserves to be more widely known. The proof -- once you know what the Stone-Cech compactification of a discrete space is -- is an easy, fun application of the Beck Monadicity Theorem.  And there's a whole cottage industry of extensions of these ideas, starting with a [description](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/relational+beta-module) of an arbitrary topological space as a kind of "lax algebra" for the ultrafilter monad.

Comment: Condition (3) looks like some sort of regularity of $\tau$ relative to $\tau^\xi$, for if $\tau = \tau^\xi$ it's just ordinary regularity, isn't it?

Comment: Well I found a pretty indirect characterization. There exist an explicitly constructible refinement $\tau'$, and $\tau$ defines a $\beta$ space iff $\tau'$ is compact and locally compact. If you want I can post it, but I think we can do better. A necessary condition though is that $X$ must be also locally compact .

Comment: @AndreaMarino I'm confused -- surely you're not saying that for any topology $\tau$ there is at most one $\tau^\xi$ which defines a $\beta$-space (since any infinite indiscrete space is a counterexample)? I'd be very interested to hear more about this!

Comment: @AndrejBauer It certainly looks like that, which is partly why I'm hopeful that it's a condition which may have been studied before...

Comment: Is the $\xi$ in $\tau^\xi$ just punctuation giving a new name, like a prime $\tau'$, or does it have some extra meaning?

Comment: @LSpice Eh, you can view it as just being like a prime. It started because I was thinking of a $\beta$ structure in terms of the structure map $\xi: \beta X \to X$, but then the formulation I arrived at didn't mention this map at all. So it's kind of a relic.

Comment: Is there any connection between these guys you are studying and the bitopological description of Priestley spaces?

Answer (score 2):

$\DeclareMathOperator\cp{cp}$We will derive some additional necessary conditions from the following

> **Observation:** Let $\tau$ be a topology on $X$ and $\tau'$ a topology refining $\tau$. Suppose that $(X,\tau')$ is compact. Then any $\tau'$-closed set is $\tau$-compact.

Indeed, it is compact in $\tau'$ because it is closed in a compact, and so it is compact also in $\tau$ because the identity $\tau' \to \tau$ is continuous.

**Consequences:** Let $(X,\tau)$ be a topological space admitting a $\beta$-structure $\tau^\xi$. Then:

1. $(X,\tau)$ is *compact* (as noted in the question).
2. $(X,\tau)$ is *locally compact* (in the sense that for every $x \in X$ there is a local base of compact neighborhoods). This follows from condition (3) on a $\beta$-space and the Observation.
3. $(X,\tau)$ is "*c-separated*": For every disjoint $C,D \subseteq X$ which are either closed or singletons, there exist compact $K,L \subseteq X$ such that $C \cap K = \emptyset$, $D \cap L = \emptyset$, and $K \cup L = X$. This follows from the fact that $(X,\tau^\xi)$ is Hausdorff, regular, and normal and the Observation.
4. $(X,\tau)$ is "*c-completely separated*": Let $C,D \subseteq X$ be disjoint and either closed or singletons. Then there exists a (not necessarily continuous) function $f: X \to [0,1]$ such that $f^{-1}(0) = C$, $f^{-1}(1) = D$, and $f^{-1}([a,b])$ is compact for every $a \leq b$. This follows from the fact that $(X,\tau^\xi)$ has the corresponding separation property and the Observation.

Note also that *if* the collection of sets with compact complement forms a topology, this this topology is the unique $\beta$-structure on $(X,\tau)$. But this is not necessarily the case.

Comment: Thanks! Remark 2 seems especially insightful to me. But I'm not sure that $cp(\tau)$ is a topology -- it's closed under finite intersections but is it closed under even finite unions? Also, in the absence of Hausdorffness, one needs to be careful about the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_compact_space) of "locally compact". I see how condition (3) and remark (2) imply that for every $x$ and every open neighborhood $U$ of $x$, there exists an open neighborhood $V$ of $x$ such that $V \subseteq K \subseteq U$ for some compact $K$ -- is this equivalent to a standard definition?

Comment: Note also that if $cp(\tau)$ is a compact Hausdorff topology, then for any $\beta$-structure $\tau^\xi$, the map $id: (X, cp(\tau)) \to (X,\tau^\xi)$ is a continuous bijection of compact Hausdorff spaces and therefore a homeomorphism. So whenever $cp(\tau)$ is a compact Hausdorff topology, it is the _unique_ $\beta$ structure on $(X,\tau)$. So I think $cp(\tau)$ must not be a topology when $X$ is an infinite indiscrete space.

Comment: Fiuu! You were right! I hope I fixed this on the edge :) however, the infinite indiscrete topology is not compact, so I don't see any contraddiction!

Comment: By locally compact I mean that - at each point - you have a local basis of compact neighbourhoods. I am quoting for Wikipedia: this is a possible definition of the local compactness, which is equivalent to the classical one if the space is Hausdorff.  The definition that I just quoted is indeed equivalent to: for any point x and open $V$ containing x, there exist an open $U$ containing x and a compact $K$ such that $U \subset K \subset V$.

Comment: If, as now, you define $cp(\tau)$ to be the topology generated by the complements of compact sets, then I think there's an error in the proof that $cp(\tau)$ is compact. The famous lemma (essentially [Cantor's intersection theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_intersection_theorem)) says that a codirected intersection of nonempty compact _closed_ sets is nonempty -- but here the $K_i$ are not necessarily $\tau$-closed (and on the other hand, they are not necessarily $cp(\tau)$-compact).

Comment: Indeed, let $(X,\tau)$ be an infinite indiscrete space. This is compact -- every open cover has a _singleton_ subcover! It's also locally compact, and compactly-separated. Then $K \subseteq X$ is $\tau$-compact for _every_ subset $K$, so $cp(\tau)$ is the discrete topology, which is not compact.

Comment: As another sanity check, Remark 2 shows that any $\tau^\xi$-open set _has_ compact complement -- not just that it's in the topology generated by the sets with compact complement. So if $\tau^\xi = cp(\tau)$ is a $\beta$-structure, then every set in the topology generated by the sets with compact complement actually _has_ compact complement, i.e. the sets with compact complement already form a topology and don't just generate one.

Comment: You are so damn right man. It didn't work! Maybe we can join forces and try to prove some other condition. I feel like we are close to! Sorry for the misunderstanding about indiscrete topology, in my mind I read "discrete" topology.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102343/discussion-between-tim-campion-and-andrea-marino).